# Setting up IAP for AppStore in Unity, received 0 products

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store

I'm trying to implement IAP for the AppStore in my app. The code is largely the same as the one in this tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game

I have created entries for the two different IAP purchases on iTunes Connect, as you can see on this screenshot:

[image: iTunes Connect]
However, I have the following error when I launch my app on iPad:

```
2017-01-09 12:10:39.298528 myApp[866:472995] UnityIAP:Requesting product data...
2017-01-09 12:10:40.683076 myApp[866:472995] UnityIAP:Received 0 products
2017-01-09 12:10:40.926407 myApp[866:472995] UnityIAP:No App Receipt found
Unavailable product POKOLPOK_GAME_02 -POKOLPOK_GAME_02
```

and same thing for the other one (`POKOLPOK_GAME_03`).

I wanted to know if the fact that the status for my IAP is set to "*Ready to Submit*" could be the source of this issue. If that's indeed the case, how can I test my IAP without Apple having to validate them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found this in one of Unity FAQ:

> 25. Why does Apple initialization return NoProductsAvailable after I set up my iTunes Account? While testing if NoProductsAvailable is
>       returned, in spite of having defined products, the iTunes Account may
>       require additional configuration. Ensure your iTunes Account also
>       contains completed agreements on tax and banking. Without these the
>       App Store may refuse to interact with an IAP client.

Turns out it was the source of the issue. If the tax and banking informations are not entered on your iTunes Account, the Unity IAP will return 0 products.

Comment: Yes, apple should give a warning in the in-app-purchase section or at least before submitting to review or App Store. Check out the agreement section once a year :)

Answer (score 7):

Ready to submit should make IAP available in SandBox. Even i followed same doc and it worked first time itself for me

Just check following items from your end 
 1. IAP in enabled in provisioning profile. Recheck if under capabilities in Xcode Project, InApp Purchase in set to ON
 2. Bundle identifier should match exactly
 3. Product should be signed with your developer / production certificate, any invalid signature will return in no products
 4. Since its Non consumable product, both products should be set for ProductType.NonConsumable type
 5. Test IAP on device using Sandbox AppleID instead of production AppleID.
 6. In iTunes connect, make sure you have done Tax & Banking setup fully.

Additionally, you might have to wait for ~24 hrs before items become available when you add it for the first time. mine started working automatically after ~12 hrs but its known fact that it can take upto 24 hrs.

If there is any other issue, you can get to know that by submitting your binary for TestFlight Beta testing. Make sure you include both of your In App purchases in iTunes connect App settings before submitting it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I check the third point (products signed with correct certificate)?

Comment: In Xcode -> General Tab -> Application Target -> Signing : Team should be set to the team you are using. That should be enough.

Comment: The step that I was missing was #5 on my iPhone

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because my bundle id (set in Unity) was spelt slightly wrong.  Therefore, the app could not find the correct app in iTunes Connect that had the relevant IAPs attached.